# can't view confusion matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

Could yo help me , I want to show my confusion matrix in readable view, as I have 18 classes so I got non readable confusion matrix when I click confusion button on neural network tool box like that image [my result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVgIq.jpg)

Please help me

Comment: any body help me please :(

Comment: please any body help me